# Prevent multiple login

Tags: asp.net

I am creating an application where users **cannot attempt multiple logins.** If a particular **user logs in**, my **database** flag **value** becomes set to **1** that means no other member who has the same username and password can login.

If a user **signs out** my **database flag value is set to 0.** That's all working fine but now I have one different **problem** that is when a **user suddenly closes the browser without logout page** or **session is timeout** then automatically the database flag value should be set to 0.

I am searching about this some articles said it can happen using global.asax file. I tried it but nothing happend so far. Please can you help me?

Comment: I'm presuming you mean global.asax instead of globel.ascx.

Comment: i sir your right by mistakenly i wrote that sorry

Comment: Hi @Aties could you post the code you put in your Session_End event handler?

Comment: Response.Write("SessionID: " +Session.SessionID.ToString() + "User key: " +(string)Session["user"]);
if(Session["user"]!=null) // e.g. this is after an initial logon
{
string sKey=(string)Session["user"];
// Accessing the Cache Item extends the Sliding Expiration automatically
string sUser=(string) HttpContext.Current.Cache[sKey];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only safe way to detect that a user has closed the browser window is through a *heartbeat*. That is, the browser keeps sending requests to the server to let it know it's still alive. Since ASP.net keeps track of the sessions, it will call your session end handler after it detects inactivity.

Therefore, if you set your session timeout to be one minute, and keep sending requests every 45 seconds, your session end handler will be called with at most one minute delay

Comment: but by default session time out is 20 min suppose im not set session timeout or browser get default session value then? is compulsory to set session value?

Comment: if you leave it at 20 minutes, it will take 20 minutes after the last request for your session end. You need to change it to a small number, since you'll be sending the heartbeats

Answer (score 2):

> **Note: closing the browser does not automatically cause Session_End event to fire**.   The Session_End event will fire after a certain amount of time as the session expires - this time-out value is set in IIS - and is set by default to 20 minutes.  The only way to set the user as inactive would be to rely on JavaScript to make an ajax request to a Web Method that ends the session.

1. Create a new Global Application Class (global.ascx) file in the root of your web application.  To do this right click your website project node in Visual Studio's solution explorer and choose 'Add - > New Item'

You will see the following dialog (in Visual Studio 2010 - other versions are similar)
 [image]

2. Click Add and view the new global.asax file's code-behind.
3. You Should now see a file with some events, one of these is `Session_End`.  Put any code that ends your users session here:

   ```
   protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // put your code that logs a user out here
   }
   ```
4. To ensure the session ends when the user closes their browser you need to rely on JavaScript **note this wont work if users have JavaScript turned off.**  On each page of the site you'll need to add something like this:

   ```
   window.onbeforeunload = function () {

       // write an ajax call to a Web Method on your site that ends the session

   }
   ```

Comment: grandpapete sir that all fine i tired in this file also but when suddenly user close browser or session is timeout out that time database value should go "0" means other person can login .this step im not getting

Comment: AJAX requests are blocked from onbeforeunload handlers, you can hack it and make it almost work but it won't work for all browsers. Also, onbeforeunload fires when you navigate to another page

Comment: The foolproof way is for the client to keep sending requests letting the server to keep the session alive, then you can set the session timeout to be just a bit more than the heartbeat interval, see my answer